# Change gravity of PopupWindow

Tags: android, popupwindow, gravity

I have a button that must show a popup window. And the popup window must be aligned with the right side of the button. That's how I do it.

```
button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick( final View view ) {
        if(popup == null) {
            final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
            popup = new PopupWindow(view);
        }

        if(popup.isShowing()) {
            popup.dismiss();
        } else {
            popup.setInputMethodMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);
            popup.setFocusable(true);
            popup.setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            popup.showAsDropDown(button, 0, 0);
        }
    }
} );
```

This code works fine but the popup window is aligned with the left side of the button. Is there an easy way to change gravity of PopupWindow?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way I've found is to specify the x-offset parameter:

```
final View view = popup.getContentView();
view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
popup.showAsDropDown(button, button.getWidth() - view.getMeasuredWidth(), 0);
```

Comment: I'd have trouble using that with ListPopupWindow though.

Comment: Where is `getContentView()`?!!

Comment: @Yahya That's a method of `PopupWindow`

Comment: Okay I see.... I busted a gut trying to fix the `popupMenu`.. it's a literal nightmare! However, `popuWindow` needs massive amount of code and implementation. I ended up preventing the mobile phone rotation to avoid this confusion!

Answer (score -5):

You can try to change it from the xml file:

```
android:layout_graviry="left"
```

Comment: PopupWindow is created as an other window, not a view, so this method doesn't work.