# Popupwindow show at location, changing the gravity gives false position

Tags: java, android

I made a popup window appear when you click on text view, i followed a guide how to create popups and i work fine, just the location of the popup is not what i want, it seems that the popup make its left top corner to show at the point location, but i want the bottom left corner to be at the specified  point like this,after searching i found that gravity is responsible for this see [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAtLocation(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int)) , but when I change the gravity to `Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.LEFT` the popup shows way above the text

The popup XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/popup"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:background="#d1a2a2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView37"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView41" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code I have

```
    vfy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Open popup window
                if (p != null)
                  showPopup(MainActivity.this, p);
            }
    });
```

These are the methods

```java
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

        int[] location = new int[2];
        TextView button = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        // Get the x, y location and store it in the location[] array
        // location[0] = x, location[1] = y.
        button.getLocationOnScreen(location);

        //Initialize the Point with x, and y positions
        p = new Point();
        p.x = location[0];
        p.y = location[1];
    }

    //............
    private void showPopup(final Activity context, Point p) {


        // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
        LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, viewGroup);

        // Creating the PopupWindow
        final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
        popup.setContentView(layout);
        popup.setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popup.setFocusable(true);

        // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
        int OFFSET_X = 30;
        int OFFSET_Y = 30;

        // Clear the default translucent background
        popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

        // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
        popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);

        // Getting a reference to Close button, and close the popup when clicked.
        TextView close = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView37);
        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popup.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use showAsDropDown() or showAtLocation() method.
Refer these links [Change gravity of PopupWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303525/change-gravity-of-popupwindow) and
[How to show PopupWindow at special location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450959/how-to-show-popupwindow-at-special-location)

Comment: I'm using showAtLocation() method but it gives wrong position when i change the gravity

Comment: Is R.layout.popup same as you mentioned above xml.