# Android PopupMenu set gravity as CENTER does not work

Tags: android, popupmenu

I tried this code.
and also tried CENTER_HORIZONTAL and CENTER_VERTICAL.
Still the anchor is at the left side of the view

```
val menu = PopupMenu(this, view, Gravity.CENTER)
menu.inflate (R.menu.menu_avatar_2)
menu.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Have look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303525/change-gravity-of-popupwindow

Answer (score 6):

You cannot control it with default `PopupMenu` and 
`PopupMenu(this, view, Gravity.CENTER)` only set the gravity of `PopuMenu` to the right of your `anchorView`.

If you really want to have gravity in text, here're the options for you:

1: Using `PopupWindow`:

```
PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(MainActivity.this);
popupWindow.setContentView(yourCustomView); // customview with list of textviews (with gravity inside)
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchorView); // display below the anchorview
```

2: using `ListPopupWindow`:

```
String[] products = {"Camera", "Laptop", "Watch", "Smartphone",
                        "Television", "Car", "Motor", "Shoes", "Clothes"};
ListPopupWindow listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(MainActivity.this);
listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(view);
listPopupWindow.setDropDownGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
listPopupWindow.setHeight(ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT);
listPopupWindow.setWidth(300);
listPopupWindow.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                            R.layout.list_item, products)); // list_item is your textView with gravity.
listPopupWindow.show();
```

Answer (score 4):

It's difficult to perfectly center-align a PopupMenu or PopupWindow to the anchor, because its position is partially determined by the length of the text labels. But you can change the horizontal and vertical offsets to make it a bit more centralized:

**styles.xml:**

```
<style name="PopupMenuMoreCentralized" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">-6dp</item>
</style>
```

**Java code:**

```
new PopupMenu(context, anchor, Gravity.CENTER, 0, R.style.PopupMenuMoreCentralized)
```

or

```
MenuPopupHelper menuPopupHelper = new MenuPopupHelper(context,
        (MenuBuilder) popupMenu.getMenu(),
        anchor,
        false,
        0,
        R.style.PopupMenuMoreCentralized);
```

Source: [Implement pop up Menu with margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449251/implement-pop-up-menu-with-margin)